# Sort Json file data by year with Angular4

Tags: json, angular, sorting, date

I have some data in a json file but it's in the wrong order, I need my data to display by a financial year rather than by a regular year.

For example instead of jan 17, feb 17, mar 17, apr 17, may 17, jun 17, jul 17, aug 17, sep 17, oct 17, nov 17, dec 17. 
It needs to be mar 17, apr 18, may 18, jun 18, jul 18, aug 18, sep 18, oct 18, nov 18, dec 18, jan 19, feb 19, apr 19, mar 19.

How can I sort my json file data so it displays in the second order?

HTML:
This is the HTML code for the display of the month data.

```
<table id ="t2">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="line">Line 1</th>
                        <th class="y18" *ngFor="let volumes of volumes">{{ volumes.month | uppercase }}</th>
                    </tr>
```

JSON:
This is an example of the JSON file.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "line": 1,
    "modelVolumes": [
        {
            "id": 367,
            "model": "car1",
            "number": 615
        },
        {
            "id": 368,
            "model": "car2",
            "num": 5925,
        },
        {
            "id": 369,
            "model": "car3",
            "num": 0
        }
    ]
},
{
        "id": 2,
        "month": "2017-04-01",
        "line": 1,
        "modelVolumes": [ ]
},
{
    "id": 12,
    "month": "2018-02-01",
    "line": 1,
    "modelVolumes": []
}
```

To understand better this is the json file with just the months:
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2017-03-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2017-04-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2017-05-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2017-06-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2017-07-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2017-08-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2017-09-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2017-10-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2017-04-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2017-04-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2017-11-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2017-12-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2018-01-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2018-02-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2018-03-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2018-04-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2018-05-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2017-03-01",
}
{
            "id": 2,
            "month": "2017-04-01",
}

Comment: how does your json look like?

Comment: Can you provide the array?

Comment: I've added some of the json to the question, basically each set has an id, month, line and model volumes which is a seperate array. I want to order  this data by the month but in the specified order.

Comment: So, isn't it like `2017-02-01` would always come first than `2017-03-01` even if it is the next financial year?

Comment: so the financial year always starts with March and ends in April. Financial year of 2018:  Apr 18, may 18, june 18, july 18, august 18, september 18, october 18, november 18, december 18, january 19, february 19, march 19. However I also need to include the last month of the financial year before so march 18 and the first month of the next finacial year so april 19.

Comment: so what about the previous financial year.... Where does that go? Can you provide an example showing atleast two financial years and how you would like to restructure your JSON?

Comment: So you mean to say, you dont want the sort but filtering of the data which is then sorted. So your problem is like given a financial year, construct a financial year from April <year> to March <year + 1> with March <year> and April <year + 1> included as well?

Comment: that sounds like it. How could I achieve that?

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try something like below. This should give you a good idea on how to implement it for your data.

```js
// Code goes here
var financialYear = 2001;

var dates = ['2000-05-01', '2001-04-01', '2001-05-01', '2001-03-01', '2001-02-01', '2002-02-01', '2002-03-01', '2002-04-01', '2002-05-01'];

var filteredDates = dates.filter(function(date){
  date = new Date(date);
        
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var mon = date.getMonth();
  
  if((year === financialYear && mon > 1) || (year === financialYear + 1 && mon < 4)){
    return true;
  }
  
  return false;
});

console.log('Filtered Dates: ', filteredDates);

var sortedDates = filteredDates.sort(function(d1, d2){
  return new Date(d1) - new Date(d2);
})

console.log('Sorted Dates: ', sortedDates);
```

Comment: I think this is along the right lines but I'm having trouble implementing this. My problem is with the date variable. It says Volumes can't be assigned to type string.

Comment: Volumes is the json file data stored in the variable volumes.  
    volumes: Volumes[];
    financialyear: 2017;
    filteredDates = this.volumes.filter(function(date) {
        date = new Date(date);

        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var mon = date.getMonth();

        if ((year === financialyear && mon > 1) || (year === financialyear + 1 && mon < 4)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    console.log('Filtered Dates: ', filteredDates);

Comment: `Volumes can't be assigned to type string`, this is due to the mismatch of types. The solution is just to give you an idea on how to implement but it would not apply directly to your problem. You need to pick up the stuff from there and once you have an array of date strings, it would work. If in case, you want to just remove that error, you can assign `volumes: any` in your code, which is not advisable though.

Comment: So I need to collect an array of date strings from the Volumes array. If I did this and the file data changed would the date strings change too.

Comment: No, you need to handle it in such a way that once the data changes, the same function gets fired again. I cannot help you much on that without seeing the code. It is a bit difficult to understand this way.